# Tables truncated with AbcPdf

Tags: truncate, abcpdf

I'm using the AbcPdf library to transform an aspx page to a pdf object. I have achieved my goal, but I have a problem. The data in the aspx page is a set of Tables, and they are dynamic, I mean, it can be 2 tables, or 30 or whatever. I have achieved that when the number of tables is bigger than one page, the library creates the required pages, but the problem is that it truncates the table.

**Question:** Is there any way in the AbcPdf library to not truncate tables or objects when the number of them is bigger than one page?

Comment: Is the generated PDF always only one page?  Can you post the code you use to chain the document together assuming you are using the AddImageUrl method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that works great:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm

```cs
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Rect.Inset(72, 144);

theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
int theID;
theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");

while (true) {
  theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border
  if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
    break;
  theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
  theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++) {
  theDoc.PageNumber = i;
  theDoc.Flatten();
}

theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("pagedhtml.pdf"));
theDoc.Clear();
```